# Load data from MySQL database to HTML textboxes on button click

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a small form for updating existing records.

[image]

I'm loading the **Service ID**s to the dropdown box using PHP. And when the user clicks the *Load* button, it is supposed to display the other details related to that ID in the textboxes below. 
Here is the code I have so far.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
//Database initialization
require_once("db_handler.php");

$conn = iniCon();
$db = selectDB($conn);

$query = "SELECT * FROM taxi_services ORDER BY SID";
$result2 = mysql_query($query, $conn);

?>

<div id="upserv">
<b id="caption2">Update location</b>
<br/><br/>
    <form name="upServForm" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post" >
        <?php
        $dropdown = "<select name='codes'>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
        {
            $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['SID']}'>{$row['SID']}</option>";
        }
        $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
    ?>
     Service ID  <?php echo $dropdown; ?> <input type="submit" value="Load" name="loadbtn">
        <table width="300" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="upName" style="text-align:right" value="<? echo $savedName; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cost</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="upCost" style="text-align:right" value="<? echo $savedCost; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Active</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="upActive" value="<? echo $savedActive; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="buttons">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" /> <input type="submit" value="Save" name="updatebtn" />
</div>
    </form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["loadbtn"]))
{
    $id = $_POST["codes"];

    $query = "SELECT Name, Cost, Active FROM taxi_services WHERE SID = '$id' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
    $details = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $savedName = $details["Name"];
    $savedCost = $details["Cost"];
    $savedActive = $details["Active"];
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

The query gets executed just fine but the data doesn't get displayed in the textboxes. Can anyone please tell me what I am missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: can you show the db table structure too

Comment: I THINK your server doesn't support [short tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). In other words, replace `<?` with `<?php`

Comment: @diEcho [here](http://i.imgur.com/9wHgG.png) it is. @Adnan I tried with `<?php ?>` too but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query has to be before the output:

Also note the typecast `(integer)` of the id to secure against sql injections.

Also note the security issues with `$PHP_SELF` http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/_SERVER_PHP.htm
I changed the code to `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`

ALso note to not use `register_globals` and disable it in the configuration if you can (use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] instead of`$SCRIPT_NAME`) : http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

If you learn php from a book and this is based on sourcecode out of this book you should throw it away immediately.

```
<?php

//Database initialization
require_once("db_handler.php");

$conn = iniCon();
$db = selectDB($conn);

$query = "SELECT * FROM taxi_services ORDER BY SID";
$result2 = mysql_query($query, $conn);

if(isset($_POST["loadbtn"]))
{
    $id = (integer) $_POST["codes"];

    $query = "SELECT Name, Cost, Active FROM taxi_services WHERE SID = '$id' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
    $details = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $savedName = $details["Name"];
    $savedCost = $details["Cost"];
    $savedActive = $details["Active"];
}

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="upserv">
<b id="caption2">Update location</b>
<br/><br/>
    <form name="upServForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="post" >
        <?php
        $dropdown = "<select name='codes'>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
        {
            $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['SID']}'>{$row['SID']}</option>";
        }
        $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
    ?>
     Service ID  <?php echo $dropdown; ?> <input type="submit" value="Load" name="loadbtn">
        <table width="300" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="upName" style="text-align:right" value="<? echo $savedName; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cost</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="upCost" style="text-align:right" value="<? echo $savedCost; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Active</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="upActive" value="<? echo $savedActive; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="buttons">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" /> <input type="submit" value="Save" name="updatebtn" />
</div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're right! That was the case. And thank you for the tip on SQLi.

Comment: @nK0de SQLi is not the right term it refers to the "new" MySQL php Extension: http://de2.php.net/mysqli please don't forget to mark the question answered :-)

Comment: Right. Got it. I always do, just had to wait till the 15 minute time limit is up. :)

Comment: @nK0de `$PHP_SELF` is a bad idea. There are security issues with it: http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/_SERVER_PHP.htm

Comment: @Thomas yes, I usually use external PHP files. This page is just a small front-end to a database that only I will be using. It will not be open to the public. So I'm not developing with security in mind too much. :)