# how to retrieve data from database and display in textbox using button

Tags: php, html

can anyone help me on how to retrieve data in database and display it in html text box when button is clicked? much appreciated thank you!

[Load data from MySQL database to HTML textboxes on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273234/load-data-from-mysql-database-to-html-textboxes-on-button-click)

already tried this but I get an error. it said that undefined variable savedname

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273234/load-data-from-mysql-database-to-html-textboxes-on-button-click

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load data from MySQL database to HTML textboxes on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273234/load-data-from-mysql-database-to-html-textboxes-on-button-click)

Comment: I'm getting an error, it said that undefined variable savedname

Comment: Are you using mysql or mysqli?

Comment: "_already tried this_" Then please post what you already have. "_but I get an error_" And again, please post what error you get. Thanks

Comment: @Sachin I'm using mysqli

Comment: @kerbholz already edited the post

Comment: initialize $savedName =  $savedCost = $savedActive = ""; top of the page and move bottom PHP code to above the your html and below the query

Answer (score 0):

Please use `<?=isset($savedName)?$savedName:"";?>` from `<? echo $savedName; ?>`.
Please use isset function in all php var use.

Comment: the error was gone, but it didn't display the data whenever i click the button.

Comment: image upload in any server and send me link in comment.

Comment: to the 1st if statement or 2nd if statement?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\oxychem\inventory\modules\addnewitems.php on line 372

Comment: not any changes only 'generate' to 'Generate' in if condition

Comment: again send me image.

Comment: Please remove $_POST['generate'] from line no 5