# Load mySql data in to HTML textBox whit PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, web-applications

I have a table of thousands of lines of code in which I have to load some data coming from a database in some of the "td" of the table ...
Wandering through SO I found several examples of uploads but all of them needed a rewrite of the whole table ...
So I ask you, is there a simpler way to pass the values ​​of a database within the table?

In simple words with a SELECT I have to be able to load data inside "td" that contain textBox.
Without the need to rewrite the table (given that there are thousands of lines) ...

I am attaching the examples I found on SO:

1° : [Load data from MySQL database to HTML textboxes on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273234/load-data-from-mysql-database-to-html-textboxes-on-button-click)

Comment: Can't really understand much and as you don't have any code example then what you except us to do?

Answer (score 0):

You want to fill a `<table>` with database datas?

1) Build your sql query.

2) Execute and retrieve datas.

3) Inject datas into `<table>` using a `foreach`.

```
<?php
    //Connection to db
    $db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'login', 'pass', 'database');

    //Query
    $sql = "SELECT name, surname FROM example";

    //Execution + error checking
    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                //Displaying results in table rows
                echo "<tr>
                        <td>".$row["name"]."</td>
                        <td>".$row["surname"]."</td>
                </tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please don't recommend using (even as an example) the _old_, _insecure_ and _deprecated_ `mysql_*`-functions. They have even been completely removed in PHP 7.

Comment: Yes sorry, I did a copy/paste of an existing project.

Answer (score 0):

To load data from MySQL/MariaDB database to table  you can use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
//This is the connection
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'DatabasePassword', 'Database Name'); ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php while ($row = $mysqli->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):  ?>
                    <?php foreach ($row as $key => $value): ?>
                    <td alt="<?=$key?>"><?=$value?></td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```